# R: Convert array to matrix with one row

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, type-conversion

Given `foo` and `mock`, is there a way to have `foo` as class `matrix` instead of `array`?

Calling `as.matrix()` puts `foo` into a wrong structure.
I would like to have `foo` being a `matrix`, just with one row instead of two.

```r
foo = structure(c(0.729504668890744, 0.190464932275543, 0.0800303988337127), 
              .Dim = c(1L, 3L, 1L), 
              .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", 
                                       "C"), "NA"))
class(foo[, , 1L])
#> [1] "numeric"
print(foo[, , 1L])
#>         A         B         C 
#> 0.7295047 0.1904649 0.0800304


mock = structure(c(0.550876469322338, 0.729504668890744, 0.342833178276825, 
                 0.190464932275543, 0.106290352400837, 0.0800303988337127), 
               .Dim = c(2L, 
                        3L, 1L), 
               .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                "NA"))

class(mock[, , 1L])
#> [1] "matrix"
print(mock[, , 1L])
#>              A         B         C
#> [1,] 0.5508765 0.3428332 0.1062904
#> [2,] 0.7295047 0.1904649 0.0800304

# matrix conversion does not result in desired structure

as.matrix(foo[, , 1L])
#>        [,1]
#> A 0.7295047
#> B 0.1904649
#> C 0.0800304
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Try `array(c(foo), dim(foo)[-3], dimnames = dimnames(foo)[1:2])`

Comment: ```t(foo[,,1L])```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `array`

```
array(c(foo), dim(foo)[-3], dimnames = dimnames(foo)[1:2])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in a generic way so that `nrow(foo)` does not have an influence on the result.

Comment: Looks like `c()` is not necessary

Comment: Why `array` and not `matrix`? -- ```matrix(mock, dim(mock)[-3], dimnames = dimnames(mock)[1:2])```

Comment: @M-- `array` is more generic can create n-dimensions while `matrix` only 2D

Answer (score 5):

You can use matrix transpose, `base::t()`:

```r
t(foo[,,1L])
#>              A         B         C
#> [1,] 0.7295047 0.1904649 0.0800304

class(t(foo[,,1L]))
#> [1] "matrix"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for `foo` but messes up the dimnames for `mock`: `t(mock[,,1L])`

Comment: @pat-s well, based on this line-- *"Given foo and mock, is there a way to have foo as class matrix instead of array?"* -- I thought you are only interested in turning `foo` to a `matrix`. In any case, glad that akrun's answer worked for you. Their answer is a generic one as you mentioned in your comment. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I missed mentioning that the solution should be nrow-agnostic in the best case. Even though this is just an added benefit. I also upvoted you, thanks for replying!